# How to prevent .slideUp after the mouse leave the button? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Helo all. How can I prevent .slideUp for my drop down menu. I want the drop down menu slide up only if I leave the area of button which is .personal-mega and the .flyout.

This is the [example][1] link that I want to achieve.

I did try to adjust the `js` but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".personal-mega").hover(            
            function() {
                $('.flyout', this).not('.in 
.flyout').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');        
            },
            function() {
                $('.flyout', this).not('.in 
.flyout').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');       
            }
        );
    });
```

Here is the snippet:
(The menu is responsive please view it with full page)

```js
$(".personal-mega").hover(function(){
    $('.flyout').slideDown("400");
});


/*
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".personal-mega").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.flyout', this).stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.flyout', this).stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});*/
```

```css
/* navbar/top navbar */
.pos-navbar{
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1000;
}

.pos-main-nav li a, .pos-top-nav li a{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.bg-pos{
 background-color: #DF1E34;
}

.pos-menu{
 border: 1px solid #DF1E34;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.pos-menu a{
 color: #DF1E34 !important;
}

.pos-menu:hover{
 transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.pos-menu:hover a{
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.pos-top-menu{
 border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

.pos-top-menu button{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
}

.pos-top-menu button:focus{
 box-shadow: none;
}

.pos-top-menu button:after{
 content: none;
}

.pos-top-menu button:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active,
.pos-top-menu button:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active,
.show>button.dropdown-toggle,
.pos-top-menu button:hover{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: transparent !important;
 border: none !important;
 border-color: transparent !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}

/*.pos-top-menu button:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active,
.pos-top-menu button:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active,
.show > button.dropdown-toggle{
 background-color: transparent !important; 
 border-color: transparent !important; 
 box-shadow: none !important; 
}*/

.pos-top-menu ul{
 padding : 0;
 top: 10px !important;
 left: -30px !important;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.pos-top-menu ul .dropdown-item{
 padding: 0;
}


.pos-top-nav li a{
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

.pos-top-nav .pos-top-menu ul li a{
 color: #666666 !important;
}

.pos-top-nav li a:active,
.pos-top-nav li a:focus,
.pos-top-nav li a:hover{
color: #333333 !important;
}

.no-link{
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
.nav-item{
 display: inline-block;
}

/* overide hover.css */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before{
 background: #DF1E34;
}

.hvr-underline-from-center:before{
 left: 50%;
 right: 50%;
 background: #DF1E34;
 height: 2px;
}

.flyout {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 background:red;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index:10000000;
}

.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- navbar -->
 <nav class="pos-navbar navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="img/pos-logo.svg" width="50%" alt="">
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="pos-main-nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item pos-menu hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
      <a class="nav-link personal-hover personal-mega" href="#">Personal</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item pos-menu hvr-sweep-to-bottom">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business</a>
     </li>

     <li class="nav-item" style="width: 20px;"></li>

     <li class="nav-item hvr-underline-from-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Digital Mailbox</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item hvr-underline-from-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shop</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item hvr-underline-from-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Promotion</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link no-link" href="#">|</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item hvr-float">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".search-modal-lg"><img src="img/icon-search.svg" width="20"></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div class="flyout hidden container-fluid">131231<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1</div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: So when does the menu actually slide up if  you didn't want to slideup after the mouse leaves?

Comment: @zer00ne Helo sorry for didn't explain it clear. The menu slide up if I leave the area of button which is `.personal-mega` and the `.flyout`. Just edit the post.

Comment: Hi thanks for the clarification, can you please remove all of the extraneous CSS? As far as I can tell in your HTML there are several classes like the prefixed `qa-` rules are not being used at all.

Comment: I really don't get it. *«How can I prevent .slideUp after the mouse leave the button before my cursor reach my dropdown menu?»* I don't get the second part. It does NOT slideUp actually on your [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-slide-down-on-hover-with-carousel). You can go from hover "Men" to the link "Feature>Auto Carousel" without any problem... Except if you pass over the "Women" button... Is that it?

Comment: @zer00ne done. =)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette here is it. "How can I prevent `.slideUp` for my drop down menu? I want the drop down menu slide up only if I leave the area of button which is `.personal-mega` and the `.flyout.`"

Comment: Okay... I was working on the example... I took time to catch it only was you "inpiration". So now... I am quite perplex of the simplicity of the challenge. Is the objective only is to make the big red div to slide up on hover out the "personnal" button? If so... It is [**here**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GyQKob?editors=1111)

Comment: REMOVE the slim version of jQuery... Since you load the full library. And since you expect animations... Slim does not include it. NEVER load two jQuery versions. **And I think that was you primary issue**

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Hello. Appreciate. Yes removed silm jQuery and thanks for explanation. For the objective is to act like a normal drop down menu. Normally drop down menu slide down while you hover the `main-menu` For me this can be settle by `<ul>` `<li>`. But in my case if I apply it into the `<li>` it will make it expand all the way down. So I have to do it separately.

Comment: You can select the top most `<li>` only... With `$("ul>li")`. Continue exploring, friend. You have much reading to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162856/discussion-between-anderson-koh-and-louys-patrice-bessette).